# Is there any way to make Parse.com configs private?

Tags: parse-platform, config, parse-cloud-code

I was hoping to use Parse's configs to set API keys for some of the different services I use (Google, Twilio, Mailgun) because I use different keys for my dev vs. production environment. The problem is that I don't want these keys to be accessible to the JavaScript client for security reasons and only want to access them from my Cloud Code. Is there any way to set that up in Parse?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store them in the Config API. If you just need them in Cloud Code, you can simply define them in a separate file or in the same file your Cloud Code functions are defined in.

That way, they are never exposed to the client and you can change them at will by deploying a new version with updated keys.